# Como simular https em http://localhost?

Tags: apache, segurança, http, ssl, localhost

Como posso simular ***https*** no Xampp de forma que ele me retorne a url mostrando se está tudo ok ou existe falhas de segurança nos scripts usados?

Comment: Para utilizar HTTPS no XAMP basta configurar o servidor web com um certificado digital servindo na porta 443. Mas não entendi o que você quiser com "falhas de segurança nos scripts usados". Que tipos de falha? Vulnerabilidades em código (como SQL Injection)? Ou você se refere apenas a recursos servidos sem criptografia (como imagens referenciadas através do protocolo http, e não https)?